# NSDateFormatter Parse Error

Tags: objective-c, ios6, nsdateformatter

I have a range of dates, all of them are on the "yyyyMMdd" format.

The problem is that when NSDateFormatter tries to parse "20121021", it returns null, on iOS 6, only.

So, I tested it on iOS 4.x and 5.x, it works perfectly. Anyone having the same issue?

Here is the code:

```
NSString *sdate = @"20121021";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:sdate];
[dateFormat release];
if (aDate){
    [dates addObject:aDate];
}else{
    NSLog(@"%@", sdate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried in ARC ios 6 - worked

Tried without ARC ios 6- Worked

```
NSString *sdate = @"20121021";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:sdate];
[dateFormat release];

if (aDate){
    NSLog(@"%@", aDate);

}else{
    NSLog(@"%@", aDate);
}
```

my log

```
2012-10-09 11:54:08.941 asd[97441:11303] 2012-10-20 18:30:00 +0000
```

Comment: Yeah, I found the problem.  I forgot to set the NSTimeZone.

Comment: By the way, it didn't work for you. You tried to parse 20121021 and got 2012-10-20 for the output...

Comment: @FernandoRocha : yah it worked see my local timezone is +5:30 so the output obtained by the dateformatter will be so only

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer... I forgot to set the NSTimeZone for the formatter.

New code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];

[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];

NSDate *aDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:sdate];
[dateFormat release];
```

Thanks